# How to download ganache on windows?

Tags: blockchain, ganache

I've been trying to download ganache on my windows machine, but I keep getting a 'failed authorization' error message.

Answer (score 1):

Since the goal is to download and install Ganache on your windows, you can get the desired version executable .exe through the steps below:

1. Navigate to https://github.com/trufflesuite/ganache-ui/tags
2. Select any desired tag with "Downloads" as shown below [image: select your desired tag with download options]
3. Scroll down to "Assets" section and select the setup exe for download as shown below [image: Select Windows .exe file]
4. Install the downloaded file.